# PDO Not escaping string quotes

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

I have a problem in a php script where I am using PDO to access my database. I can't seem to get PDO to escape my string when I use `prepare()`or `execute()`in PDO. I've looked all over and I haven't found an answer to this problem because everywhere I look it says PDO automatically escapes the strings.
Here's my code :

```
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Table (ID, Column1, Column2) VALUES (NULL, '$var1', '$var2')");
$query->execute();
```

Let's admit `$var1 = "abc'def"` and `$var2 = "123"` The problem is I get an error message because the quote wasn't escaped.

> Error : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'def',
>   '123')' at line 1

I've also tried using the `query()` method but same prpblem with the quotes.
I really don't understand and it's frustrating. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check out the [examples](http://ca.php.net/pdo.prepare).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Took out ID, as it should be auto_increment and handled by database
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Table (Column1, Column2) VALUES (:col1, :col2)");

$statement->bindValue(':col1', $var1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':col2', $var2, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$statement->execute();
```

Comment: No problem. For future reference, read the PHP docs, 95% of the time there are great examples from which glean how to implement the api calls correctly. Accept when you can.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the bindParam() method of the PDO library.

This makes your query look like this:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Table (ID, Column1, Column2) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)");
$statement->bindParam(1, $var1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(2, $var2, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$query->execute();
```

//I really should load the new answers :) When the bar says there are.

Comment: As Mike Purcell suggested it I did it with a similar method called `bindValue()`I prefer keys rather than indexes for objects in a string.

Comment: This approach will work the same, the only downfall is if you have a query with a high number of params, it can get confusing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for that purpose. Have a look at www.php.net/addslashes

Comment: Why should you use addslashes when the PDO extension has built in functions for that?

Comment: You probably shouldn't. Wasnt't aware PDO has the ability do solve such thing.